# Piece of paper with a solution

Tags: the-witness

Immediately after you leave the entry are there is a huge door with puzzle on it. You learn how to solve it buy following the path past it to the next puzzles. If you return and to it successfully it opens the door to a room with table like chest where you get a piece of paper with a zig-zagy solution to a bee-hive like challenge to (i'm assuming) a future door.

Why is this there, where should it be used, and what difference would using it makes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The piece of paper gives you a solution that you can enter into the hexagon puzzle below the Windmill.

This is completely optional.

Comment: Note: I modified this answer to remove a spoiler as to what the puzzle actually does.

Comment: I figured its optional as this door wasn't mandatory to go trough. I'll take it the game does different things if you use this solution or not. I'll have to get there to see for myself I guess.

Comment: The hexagon puzzle has... 6 solutions that you can find around the island.